# SSE intrinsics: How to store values to the register?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I'm very new to SSE intrinsics and have a small problem. I need help in loading integer values to the `__m128i`

Here is what I already have:

```
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi16( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 );
__m128i b = _mm_set_epi16( 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8 );

//some magic
__m128i c // = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Comment: Go read some of the links at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, esp. Agner Fog's guides.  (http://agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: thanks this was very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself

```
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi16( 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4 );
__m128i b = _mm_set_epi16( 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8 );

//some magic
__m128i mmShufflerVo = _mm_set_epi8(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, 12, 9, 8,5, 4,1, 0);
__m128i mmShufflerHi = _mm_set_epi8(13, 12, 9, 8, 5, 4, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 
                                          -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);

__m128i mmResult0_3 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mmResult0_3, mmShufflerVo);

__m128i mmResult4_7 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(mmResult4_7, mmShufflerHi);


__m128i c = _mm_or_si128(mmResult0_3, mmResult4_7);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load the values dynamically then you can use the set intrinsics:

[intrinsics for loading data to the sse registers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/48z274sd(v=vs.90).aspx)

e.g.:

```
__m128i c  = _mm_set_epi16(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); //load 8 16-bit integers to the register
```